# i have 5 strings some are changing dynamically but some can't

Tags: java, android, string, random

actually i am new to programming, but i tried this for a simple math game. Here in this program i made s1,s2,s3,s4 & s5 to generate dynamically.. but only s1, s2 are changing, s3,s4,s5 are not changing if the method calls again... please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button b1, b2, b3;
ImageView i, i2, i3;
TextView t1, t2, t3;
String s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;

int m, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, n[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    imp();

}

public void imp() {
    Random r1 = new Random();
    r2 = r1.nextInt(15) + 1;
    r3 = r1.nextInt(15) + 1;
    r4 = r2 + r3;
    r5 = r2 - r3;
    r6 = r2 * r3;

    n = new int[] { r4, r5, r6 };

    while (r9 == r11 || r9 == r13 || r11 == r13) {
        r8 = r1.nextInt(3) + 0;
        r9 = n[r8];
        r10 = r1.nextInt(3) + 0;
        r11 = n[r10];
        r12 = r1.nextInt(3) + 0;
        r13 = n[r12];
    }
    s1 = Integer.toString(r2);
    s2 = Integer.toString(r3);
    s3 = Integer.toString(r9);
    s4 = Integer.toString(r11);
    s5 = Integer.toString(r13);
    t1.setText(s1);
    t2.setText(s2);
    b1.setText(s3);
    b2.setText(s4);
    b3.setText(s5);

    int[] images = { R.drawable.plus, R.drawable.minus, R.drawable.multiply };

    Random random = new Random();
    m = images[random.nextInt(images.length)];
    i.setImageResource(m);
}

public void click(int k, Button b) {
    if (m == R.drawable.plus && k == r4 || m == R.drawable.minus && k == r5
            || m == R.drawable.multiply && k == r6) {

        imp();

    } else {
        t3.setText("FINISH");
        t3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b.setPressed(true);
        b1.setClickable(false);
        b2.setClickable(false);
        b3.setClickable(false);

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        click(r9, b1);

        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        click(r11, b2);
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        click(r13, b3);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

and the layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.97"
    android:editable="false"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="67dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plus" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.00"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <Button
      android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
<Button
     android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
     android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
android:text="Large Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textSize="50dp" 
android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are r9, r11, r13 changing? You will learn debugging skills here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your while loop, the second time you run through that method, the condition cannot possibly be true because the results from the last time through are remembered.  I would recommend using local variables instead of fields for those answers.  You could continue using fields by setting each of r9, r11, and r13 to 0; however, there is no good reason for them to be fields.  You only need these variables until you set the button text.  Now, for local variables you do need to initialize them to 0, they don't have a value by default like fields do.

If you don't mind me giving some unsolicited advice as well, I'd recommend you use slightly more descriptive variable names.  For example:

```
while (result1 == result2 || result1 == result3 || result2 == result3) {
    randomIndex1 = random.nextInt(3) + 0;
    result1 = resultArray[randomIndex1];
    randomIndex2 = random.nextInt(3) + 0;
    result2 = resultArray[randomIndex2];
    randomIndex3 = random.nextInt(3) + 0;
    result3 = resultArray[randomIndex3];
}
```

This results in code that's easier to understand for other people. (And for yourself in the future!)